# Why reseting setInterval it continues to call multiple function instance not one?

Tags: javascript, timer

I have problem to pause and play `setInterval`, whenever I `clearInterval` and `var = setInterval(func,time)`, it multiplies the instances on interval, and it starts to call 2 func per tick and so on.

Here is jsfiddle with non-working example http://jsfiddle.net/wZWWT/

Here is the code:

```
function test() {
 $(".container").append("<div>Inserted text</div>");   
}

var timer = setInterval(test,2000);

$(".container").on("mouseenter mouseover",function(){
    clearInterval(timer);
}).on("mouseleave mouseout",function(){
    timer = setInterval(test,2000);
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Makes sense. Mouseleave and mouseout are two different events. So you've got two intervals created.

When you create a new interval the old one isn't destroyed. It continues working even if you don't store the reference to it

before setting a new interval try to check if you've another interval running:

```
$(".container").on("mouseenter mouseover",function(){
    clearInterval(timer);
}).on("mouseleave",function(){
    if ( !timer ) timer = setInterval(test,2000);
}).on("mouseout",function(){
    if ( !timer ) timer = setInterval(test,2000);
})
```

Comment: Or just choose between `mouseenter` or `mouseover`. Most likely only `mousenter/mouseleave` is wanted. If `mouseover/mouseout` is wanted, then it'll also fire on the `.container`, so there should be no need for both.

Comment: @squint agreed. It's just a template for this kinda thing

Answer (score 1):

The `timer` is actually just an integer that represents the `setInterval()`. If you assign a new `setInterval()` to it, then `timer` will have the ID of the new `setInterval()` but the old one is not cancelled, and you don't know the ID for it to do so with the ID overwritten.

In your code the `on()` is calling both `mouseenter` and `mouseover` - both are firing but only the ID of the last one to execute is set to the `timer` variable, so when it is called (twice, but it doesn't really do any harm) in your `mouseleave/mouseout` it can only cancel one of them.